# Excel Worksheet protection, with VBA for the

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA code that runs on the workbook open event to enable worksheet protection for all worksheets. Every other time I open the workbook the worksheet protection is not turned on. I am completely perplexed at what could cause this. The code is:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim WKS As Worksheet
Dim WBK As Workbook
Set WBK = ThisWorkbook
For Each WKS In WBK.worksheets
    WKS.Protect Password:="xyz", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
Next WKS
WBK.Protect Password:="xyz"
End Sub

'  This is the before close event to make sure the user menu tab is active  on open.
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim wsCurrent As Worksheet
Dim WSNew As Worksheet
Dim WBK As Workbook
Dim WKS As Worksheet

Set WBK = ThisWorkbook
Set wsCurrent = ActiveSheet
application.DisplayAlerts = False
If wsCurrent.Name = "Menu" Then
    For Each WKS In WBK.worksheets
        WKS.Protect (PW())
    Next WKS
    WBK.Save
Else
    Set WSNew = application.worksheets("Menu")
    WBK.Unprotect (PW())
    WSNew.Visible = True
    wsCurrent.Visible = False
    For Each WKS In WBK.worksheets
        WKS.Protect (PW())
    Next WKS
    WBK.Save
End If
End Sub

'This is the PW function
Function PW()
PW = "xyz"
End Function
```

Comment: Is it in the `thisworkbook` module?

Comment: I suggest you write msgbox "wb_open started" at the start of the event. Save and reopen the workbook, set a stop point after the msgbox, then use F8 to go through each line. Which ones don't do what you expected?

Comment: It is in Microsoft Excel Objects" --> "thisworkbook."  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @ David GM, I have put a break in at the beginning of the subroutine.  It appears to work normally, but every other time I open the workbook it's not called.  I don't understand how this happens, though.

Comment: @ David GM, I tried it again just to review.  The first time through it runs perfectly.  When I close the workbook and open it again, the breakpoint is dropped and the workbook is not protected.  The first time around it was protected with the line WKP.Protect Password: = "xyz"

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the source of my difficulties.  I needed to unprotect the workbook at the beginning of the routine and then protect it at the end again.  I was only protecting it at the end.  The revised code is:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim WKS As Worksheet
Dim WBK As Workbook
Set WBK = ThisWorkbook
WBK.Unprotect Password:="xyz"
For Each WKS In WBK.worksheets
    WKS.Protect Password:="xyz", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
Next WKS
    WBK.Protect Password:="xyz"
End Sub
```